# Shadow box overlay hiding flash

Tags: actionscript-2, shadowbox

I have a site that's mostly made in flash. And the flash triggers shadowbox. But when shadowbox kicks in, the site isn't visible behind the box.

Any thoughts?

Comment: It's difficult at times to get flash to stay behind certain elements. Are you sure Shadowbox doesn't hide any flash elements beneath it until a later time?

Comment: It hides the flash so that it will keep on playing when I close shadow box. The music is still playing (at least in FF not in IE another problem). But it doesn't show it's content because I can see the background behind the flash.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the rendering engine of the browser won't allow flash to be part of transparency? Or maybe the overlay isn't really transparent? Is it just that the area around the overlay doesn't show, or is that you can't see through the overlay to the flash where it should be partially transparent?

It seems to me that if you have a non-transparent (a gif or jpeg) then even if you set the element to be transparent then it might not play nice with flash. Maybe try and make a .png image that is already transparent without any html/css styling?

Though a thought comes to mind, if you already have mostly flash, why not do the overlays in flash as well? Those would be possibly more featureful and have more customization.

Answer (score 0):

search "r.style.visibility" and make sure it is set to "visible"

Answer (score 0):

it is troubleElements option
http://www.shadowbox-js.com/options.html

you can also disable toggleTroubleElements() on K.onOpen();